# First Order differential equation with dirac delta function for Neuron models

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in Neuronal Dynamics and reading Gerstner's book recently. At some point I couldn't implement dirac delta function for neuron. So I need your help.

Best regards. [Neuron model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49LuC.jpg)

Comment: Hi :) the general user of this platform doesn't really like pictures. You would be advised to write it out here instead of on paper

Comment: Thx. How can I write it in symbolic way?

Comment: Google "mathjax".

Comment: if you aren't familiar with MathJax formatting, please see this [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/11491#11491)

Comment: It will take some effort to learn MathJax. As soon as possible I will fix it. Until this, any help will be appreciated. Thx.